# Элементы вокруг блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как можно сверстать такой блок адаптивно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в смысле адаптивно ?дизайнер как нарисовал смартфон версию ?Такое в смартфон не впихнуть как на картинке

Comment: @Избытоксусликов да впихнуть можно, но масштаб будет 0_о...

Comment: Спрашивайте у дизайнера, а не у нас

Comment: @andreymal Наверняка, ещё и навигация с анимацией при скролле, как здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882464/265406  Тогда вообще засада))

Comment: @UModeL оч. понравилось анимация которое ты там в ссылке реализовал :) .А что насчет внедрения такие вещи обычно для смартфонов не делают смотри на этот сайт похожое как тут http://en.euro.vet/ у них моб. версии нету

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть несколько вариантов - либо сверстать как есть, и на мобильных - это будет маленький, не читаемый блок. Либо можно делать это всё картинкой, чтобы можно было приблизить и рассмотреть. Ещё один вариант, и это самый нормальный - это попросить дизайнера или спросить у заказчика видение данного блока, с учётом адаптивности. И объяснить, что данный блок стоит переделать иначе, как минимум в мобильной версии, чтобы всё корректно отображалось и читалось на всех платформах.